# Is it possible to combine two FileList objects?

Tags: javascript, object, filelist

I have a FileList object which holds previously uploaded documents. I'm trying to use another function to add more files to this collection, by using another FileList object, so I need to "append" the secondary FileList object onto the primary one. How would it be possible to achieve this?

Comment: I think this question can also answer the question of adding or pushing a new file to FileList object, so I'll edit it to answer that question simultaneously

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to first convert the `FileList` objects to Arrays, after which you can simply `concat` the multiple arrays.

```
const joined = Array.from(fileListA).concat(Array.from(fileListB));
```

Comment: But probably author of the question wants to get another FileList as a result

Answer (score 1):

```
const filesArray = [...filesList1, ...filesList2];
console.log(filesArray) // [File, File, File, File, File, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer clarifies the path completely. A temp variable can also be used here, like the following:

```
 var temp = files
 files=Array.prototype.slice.call(temp).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.files))
```

Also in React for setting the files in the state the following code can be used inside handleInputChange function:

```
 var temp = this.state.files;         
 this.setState({
        files: Array.prototype.slice.call(temp).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.files))
   })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var fileLists = [fileListA, fileListB];
var files = fileLists.reduce(function(a, c) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.call(Object.values(a), Object.values(c))
})
```