# How to combine two FileList objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, webapi

Given that an [`FileList` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) isn't a typical array, I'm not sure how to (if possible) to combine or concant 2 `FileList` objects.

If placed in a function, it should have a signature like `FileList fn(FileList A, FileList B)`.

I have seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111348/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-filelist-objects) asking something similar, but the given answers does not achieve the intended outcome.

Trying to convert the object into an Array does not work, since its inherently not a array-type.

Using a loop to iterate the individual `FileList` might allow reading of values, but how do combine and return a single `FileList` object?

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?